# Kubernetes NodePort not listening

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, k3s

I'm doing some tutorials using k3d (k3s in docker) and my yml looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:alpine
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

With the resulting node port being 31747:

```
:~$ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.43.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        18m
nginx        NodePort    10.43.254.138   <none>        80:31747/TCP   17m

:~$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME         ENDPOINTS         AGE
kubernetes   172.18.0.2:6443   22m
nginx        10.42.0.8:80      21m
```

However wget does not work:

```
:~$ wget localhost:31747
Connecting to localhost:31747 ([::1]:31747)
wget: can't connect to remote host: Connection refused
:~$
```

What have I missed? I've ensured that my labels all say `app: nginx` and my `containerPort`, `port` and `targetPort` are all 80

Comment: Is it even possible to hit this using `localhost`? Is the cluster running on Docker network `host`? Please clarify. You can also try `kubectl port-forward pod/<podname> 8080:80` and `curl localhost:8080` to verify Pod IP is fine.

Comment: yes when I run `kubectl port-forward pod/<podname> 8080:80` wget works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is, is the NodePort range mapped from the host to the docker container acting as the node. The command `docker ps` will show you, for more details you can `docker inspect $container_id` and look at the `Ports` attribute under `NetworkSettings`. I don't have k3d around, but here is an example from kind.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                       NAMES
1d2225b83a73        kindest/node:v1.17.0          "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours         127.0.0.1:32769->6443/tcp   kind-control-plane
```

```
$ docker inspect kind-control-plane
[
    {
        # [...]
        "NetworkSettings": {
            # [...]
            "Ports": {
                "6443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                        "HostPort": "32769"
                    }
                ]
            },
        # [...]
    }
]
```

If it is not, working with `kubectl port-forward` as suggested in the comment is probably the easiest approach. Alternatively, start looking into Ingress. Ingress is the preferred method to expose workloads outside of a cluster, and in the case of kind, [they have support](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/ingress/) for Ingress. It seems k3d also has a way to [map the ingress port to the host](https://k3d.io/usage/guides/exposing_services/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll need to read up on ingress vs nodeport service, but it looks like ingress is indeed the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't expose the ports when creating the cluster

https://k3d.io/usage/guides/exposing_services/

Answer (score 0):

maybe, your pod is running on the other work node, not localhost. you should use the correct node ip.

Comment: How would the OP confirm this?